# Savepoint in PostgreSql Function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, savepoints

I want to use savepoint feature inside a function in PostgreSQL. I read that savepoint cannot be used inside functions in Postgres.

But while I rollback, I want to rollback to a specific point because of which I want to use savepoint. What is the alternative way to do it?

Sample Code

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION fn_loadData_Subha()
RETURNS BIGINT 
AS 
$$
DECLARE
    batchId BIGINT;   
    currentTime TIMESTAMP;
    processName VARCHAR(20);
BEGIN


-- Getting current date and time
select TIMESTAMP 'NOW' into currentTime;
select 'ETL_Subha' INTO processName;

SAVEPOINT first_savepoint;
-- Inserting new record into batch log table
INSERT INTO TB_HSS_BATCH_LOG
(PROCESS_NAME,START_DATE,STATUS)
SELECT processName,currentTime,'STARTED';

select currval('TB_HSS_BATCH_LOG_id_seq') INTO batchId;

-- Inserting cost data to history table
    Insert into tb_hss_procedure_cost_hist1
    (HOSP_SYSTEM, HOSP_FACILITY, surgeon_name, procedure_name, department, current_dept_rank, no_of_surgeons, current_imp_cost
     , current_med_surg_cost, current_total_cost, annual_volume, sys_pref_cost,load_seq_no, CREATED_AT)
    Select  
    HOSP_SYSTEM, HOSP_FACILITY,surgeon_name,procedure_name,department,current_dept_rank, no_of_surgeons, current_imp_cost
    , current_med_surg_cost, current_total_cost, annual_volume, sys_pref_cost, batchId,currentTime
    from tb_hss_procedure_cost_stag_in; 

RELEASE SAVEPOINT first_savepoint;    
RETURN 1;


EXCEPTION
WHEN PLPGSQL_ERROR THEN 
  RAISE EXCEPTION '% %', SQLERRM, SQLSTATE; 
  RAISE NOTICE '% %', SQLERRM, SQLSTATE; 
  RETURN 0;
WHEN OTHERS THEN
  RAISE EXCEPTION '% %', SQLERRM, SQLSTATE; 
  RAISE NOTICE '% %', SQLERRM, SQLSTATE; 
  RETURN 0;
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

END;
$$LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: You need `rollback to first_savepoint`: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-rollback-to.html

Comment: You cannot use any transaction related SQL statements inside a PostgreSQL function.

Comment: rollback to first_savepoint does not work inside function as savepoint cannot be used inside function. I want to know alternative of savepoint..

Answer (score 10):

The way to use savepoints in PL/pgSQL functions is to use a `BEGIN ... EXCEPTION ... END` block. Under the hood, this sets a savepoint at `BEGIN` and rolls back to it when an exception is encountered.

So your code could look like that (I'm not 100% sure if I read your code correctly):

```
DECLARE
   batchid bigint;
   processname varchar(20) := 'ETL_Subha';
BEGIN
   BEGIN
      INSERT INTO TB_HSS_BATCH_LOG
         (PROCESS_NAME,START_DATE,STATUS)
         VALUES (processname,current_timestamp,'STARTED')
         RETURNING id INTO batchid;
      RETURN 1;
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
         RETURN 0;
   END;
END;
```

Some general remarks to your code:

- `batchid` is never used.
- `currenttime` is unnecessary – every call to `current_time` will return the same value in a transaction.
- Raising an exception with `RAISE` will terminate execution. If you want an error to be thrown, just don't catch the original exception; it will be more meaningful than your exception. My code above assumes that you want to catch the exception and want to return 0 instead.
- `SELECT val INTO variable` is the same as `variable := value` under the hood, but the latter is generally considered more readable.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz.. The Code is a partial code..so it has some unused stuffs which are actually used in the later part.

Comment: No I dont want to Return 0, I want to rollback to a particular point(alternative to Savepoint as Savepoint cannot be used inside function)..that is the most important reason why I posted this question..

Comment: Like I wrote, as soon as you enter the `EXCEPTION` block, you *have* rolled back to the savepoint.

Comment: I could not introduce any savepoint in the function as it was not allowed..

Comment: I said: *The way to use savepoints in PL/pgSQL functions is to use a `BEGIN ... EXCEPTION ... END` block. Under the hood, this sets a savepoint at BEGIN and rolls back to it when an exception is encountered.* So you already have introduced a savepoint if you write such a block.